# Creating email messaging system on web application

Tags: php, mailer

Just a general email question. I'm working on an application that allows clients to connect (via email) with teachers of subjects they are interested in learning. Dating websites as well as social media websites like LinkedIn have emailing features that I would like. All messages are visible on the app and it appears (at least in LinkedIn's case) that email addresses remain private for safety reasons. I currently have PHP mailer installed on the site and I am using mailtrap as an SMPT server for testing, which I have gotten to work just fine. Here is the functionality I have so far:

A potential student views a profile of an instructor, clicks the contact button and can send that instructor an email without seeing that instructor's email address. I can then write that outgoing message to a text file and display it in a messaging center along with the date and time it was sent.

What I don't know how to do is handle the reply. After they send the message via PHP mailer, the instructor would just hit reply and send their response directly to the student's private email, so I would have no way to display it on my app. I would like to be able handle all messaging directly on the app. What would that entail? I am comfortable in PHP, but I am completely new to setting up email and only recently got PHP mailer set up and working. I'm hoping someone can get me going in the right direction. Any advice or resources would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using an e-mail service to handle this functionality.  Many of them have an API.  The reason is that it's pretty difficult to stay off spam blacklists, even if you're doing everything correctly.  Using a good mail provider means you don't have to worry about it.  Your choice of provider may dictate how you handle replies.  (Some accept inbound mail, some don't.)

Comment: Are there a few you could recommend I check out? Would it be your guess that a big site like LinkedIn uses an email service to handle their communications?

Comment: I also thought that maybe I could create my own messaging system using file_put_contents() and file_get_contents, saving all messages on text files in the appropriate folder for different user accounts.

Comment: @Skinsfan [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) delivery service will keep sent emails out of spam - and company maintains WP plugin. I also like Sparkpost, but they stopped maintaining WP plugin.

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions. I will look into those.